# Mapping columns to lines

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with the following fields:

```
AS1|BS1|AS2|BS2|AS3|BS3|
...N rows...
```

I would like to create a new table, based on the first one, with the following structure:

```
Label|S1|S2|S3|
  A  |  |  |  | (This row contains the value of AS1|AS2|AS3)
  B  |  |  |  | (This row contains the value of BS1|BS2|BS3)
...(2*N rows total because there was 2 type of label)...
```

I know how to do it un C#, but is there anyway to directly do it with a SQL statement?

What I have tried to far:

```
SELECT "A" as LABEL, AS1 as S1, AS2 as S2, AS3 FROM MyTABLE
```

But how to do the same for the "B" label in the same SQL statement?

*My quetion is for MS ACCESS DB but feel free to use any SQL you know, I'll try to adapt it for ACCESS if possible.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a UNION ALL

```
select 'A' as Label
   , AS1 as S1
   , AS2 as S2
   , AS3 as S3
from Table
UNION ALL
select 'B' as Label
   , BS1 as S1
   , BS2 as S2
   , BS3 as S3
from Table
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/union-operation-microsoft-access-sql) the two sets together, e.g.:

```
select 'A' as label, t1.as1 as s1, t1.as2 as s2, t1.as3 as s3
from mytable t1
union all
select 'B' as label, t2.bs1 as s1, t2.bs2 as s2, t2.bs3 as s3
from mytable t2
```